ContentFilter in RTI Subscriber with c++
I want to create create_Content in subscriber side in RTI with CPP
i am receiving a multiple packet which can contain different ip out of this i want to filter based on some specific ip
and this set of ip can be change in between/while running so how to reset again without creating new subscriber ,reader everything again.
DDS_String_dup function is not working for setting ip in DDS_StringSeq anyone know why???
Here is the example packet that I am receiving :-
packet 1 = 1.1.1.1
packet 2 = 1.1.1.2
packet 3 = 1.1.1.3
packet 4 = 1.1.1.4

at starting i want to filter only for ip 1.1.1.2 and 1.1.1.1
but after some time i want to filter for 1.1.1.3 also (so for all three basically).
I am using gcc 4.4.7
